# Stop program execution in typescript

Tags: typescript

Practising with Javascript, if i want to test a block of code

```
function logic(a, b){
   x= a+b;
   y = x-5;
   console.log(y);
   return; // This is my break statement to make sure the function runs until y.

  z = y*10; //This line is not executed.
}
```

Now while practicing with typescript with angular2, if i use a return

```
logic(a, b) => {
       x= a+b;
       y = x-5;
       console.log(y);
       return; // Throws error

      z = y*10; //I need to comment out this line to avoid error
    }
```

It says **unreachable code detected**. Is there any way i can stop the execution.

Answer is update tsconfig.json in root folder

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": true, //add this line
        "lib": [
            "es2016"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: what about `break;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, set `--allowUnreachableCode`. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html